# iOS 7 - Restrict landscape orientation only in one view controller

Tags: ios

I need to open the first view controller only in portrait mode. As the rest view controllers will use both orientation. So i have added both orientation in plist file.

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    //Never called
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    //Never called
}
```

can any one tell me how to restrict

Comment: you should use navigation controller for your case

Comment: @Nabeel, Have you got the answer of your question. If yes please share

Comment: I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it simply by creating UINavigationController class and overriding

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if(appDelegate.isOrientationOn) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Use this custom navigation controller class in root window and that's all.

Comment: what does appDelegate.isOrientationOn means, it is giving error!

Comment: @AsifHabib it is your logic :)

Comment: Clean, easy, efficient solution. Coding as an art!

Answer (score 2):

This will lock your View Controller's Orientation in Portrait Mode:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: But these methods are not calling on new screen load.