# Support Orientation in a TabBar Controller and navigation Controller App ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

Hi there i have a **tabBarController** which contain 4 tabs and each of the tabs has its own **navigation controller** , is it possible to have rotation only in some of the **viewControllers**.

i am using a method like this on AppDelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
         isKindOfClass:[ChatController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {

        if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController]
             isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

            // look for it inside UINavigationController
            UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

            // is at the top?
            if ([nc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[ChatController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

                // or it's presented from the top?
            } else if ([[nc.topViewController presentedViewController]
                        isKindOfClass:[ChatController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            }

            UITabBarController *tb = (UITabBarController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
            if ([tb.tabBarController isKindOfClass:[ChatController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

                // or it's presented from the top?
            } else if ([[tb.tabBarController presentedViewController]
                        isKindOfClass:[ChatController class]]) {
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
            }
        }
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

maybe **TabBarController** isn't good 
or there is any approach 
plz let me know

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768620/ios-7-restrict-landscape-orientation-only-in-one-view-controller

Comment: orientation adjustments are almost same for navigation bar and tab bar  in iOS 7. Hence the above link.

Comment: in this method i dont get isORientationON

'-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if(appDelegate.isOrientationOn) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}'

Comment: U need to add that method in the viewcontroller class that you don't want to rotate.

Comment: which one cuz obviously i dont get it.
if this is the solution how do i get isOrientationOn variable ...
is simply what is isOrientationOn