# How to rotate only the subclassed mpmovieplayer controller and keeping other views fixed to portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using xcdYoutubeVideoViewController which is subclassed from MPMoviePlayerController. My application is in portrait. To launch the movieplayer, I am doing this:

```
UINavigationController *navBarController = (UINavigationController*)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] ;
[navBarController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc];
```

where vc is instance of XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController. How can I allow rotation only in this view and on pressing done button in movieplayer bring the application back to portrait?

Comment: Possibly duplicate check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768620/ios-7-restrict-landscape-orientation-only-in-one-view-controller

Comment: yes, its a navigationcontroller. I did this:  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:btVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController; where btVC is subclassed from UIViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override: `-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate` in each view controller. Return YES if you want that view controller to rotate NO otherwise. Be sure to check the supported orientation on your storyboard setting.

**Update:** In your parent controller that presents the player try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     // 1. check if the parent presentedViewController is the nav containing the player

     // 2. if yes, return YES, NO otherwise
}
```

If the app root controller is a Navigation Controller, subclass `UINavigationViewController` and use that class in creating the app root view controller in App Delegate

```
@implementation ANavigationViewControllerSubClass


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{ 
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.topViewController   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation]; 
}
```

Comment: Overrriding shouldAutorotate doesn't help. Where do I need to use preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation? Should it be in parent view or movieplayer?

Comment: Question: What is the root controller of the app, is it a UINavigationView Controller?

Comment: yes, its a navigationcontroller. I did this: UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:btVC]; self.window.rootViewController = navController; where btVC is subclassed from UIViewController

Comment: Also I have added support for all orientation in app settings so that it doesn't block my movie player from rotating . But now, everything rotates.

Comment: Hey.. what exactly is topViewController here

Comment: It is the view controller at the top of navigation stack. The last pushed view controller by a UINavigationViewController.