# ios 7 orientations responds only in 1 viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have deselected the`checkboxes`inside the blue file that are responsible for orientations , 
because I don't want my app to respond to the orientations changes , expect 1 single view controller , is it possible to make that only view controller to respond to orientations ?

I have seen some similar questions , but they were using story board and I don't use them...
is there any programmatically solution ?

The `viewController` is presented `modaly`

i am calling the `viewController` this way

```
    youtubePlayerViewController * yt = [[youtubePlayerViewController alloc]initWithYoutubeId:@"5d3zDO14PD0"];
    [self presentViewController:yt animated:YES completion:nil];
```

inside it :

I have tried a lot of thing , in the end I have ended up trying to force it to go back landscape orientation but it just doesn't respond :(

however if I allowing the checkboxes in the blue file , it works , BUT all my app is not meant to run only in portrait :-/

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
        return (YES);
    return (NO);
}
```

Comment: Not clear, What are you asking for? "blue file"?

Comment: Can you check my answer: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638064/how-to-rotate-only-the-subclassed-mpmovieplayer-controller-and-keeping-other-vie/25638142#25638142)

Comment: @mehulpatel inside Xcode IDE , the "project file" it is blue , sorry I don't know how it calls , but there is all the preference of the project , and also the orientations are there inside `general ` deployment info

Comment: @Allan that means to go for each `viewController` and dissable orientations , instead of just enable it in 1 `viewController` :(

Comment: @Allan is there the opposite solution ?

Comment: @user3351949: If you want to disable orientation in specific view controllers. Create a sub class of `UIViewController` and then add your code in it. Then just override this class to your view controller in which you don't want orientation.

Comment: @mehulpatel That's interesting , if I will not find better solution I guess I will use it , thanks ... however it is sad... I have too many view controllers to change :(

Comment: I agree with @mehulpatel. Just a suggestion: You can exercise creating your own base class atleast for UIViewController and extend it by viewcontroller your going to create, so that you could easily modify a global behaviour for all the view controller.

Comment: @Allan  
I gave up and used ur suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subclass UINavigationViewController for the class you want to support multiple orientation and in ThatClass.m add

```
  // < iOS 6    
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
     }

   // > iOS6
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
      return NO;
     }

   // > iOS6
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry for being dumb , but what is the mention of `subclassing` the `UINavigationViewController` , I should add new file that will extend the `UINavigationViewController` -> but what to put inside of it ? I mean how is it work ? how should I call my `modalviewControlelr` via the `navigationViewController`?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Comment: change // > iOS6
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate to return NO

Answer (score 0):

**1.If you rootView is UITabbarConroller. add this code in your TabbarController**

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

//only rotate in NeedRotateController
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    UINavigationController * baseNavCtr = self.viewControllers[self.selectedIndex];
    if ([baseNavCtr.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NeedRotateController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

**2.if rootView is UINavgationController**

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.topViewController isKindOfClass:[NeedRotateController class]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

**3.if this not work ,checkout your AppDelegate.m or info.plist support Rotate ？**

Comment: ...and what is exactly that mysterious `NeedRotateController`? you answer make no sense in the current context.

Comment: The only view controller to your want to respond to orientations